# Codeigniter Multiple database connection Access Denied issue

Tags: codeigniter, multiple-databases

in **database.php**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'bd1',
    'password' => 'pass3214',
    'database' => 'db1',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['conncetdbtest'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'db2',
    'password' => 'pass123',
    'database' => 'db2',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

in **test.php** in **view**

```
<?php

$DB2 = $this->load->database('conncetdbtest' , TRUE);
$querydb2 = $DB2 ->select('*')->get('test');
print_r($querydb2);

?>
```

When I run the the code , showing me Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'db2'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Do not able to solve . Please help me .

Comment: using control panel username and password may solve the problem

Comment: Did you try to login to your SQL server using that credentials? (using phpmyadmin or similar tool)
I thing you are using the wrong credentials

Comment: thank you to all , my issue is already solved . This problem was occur related to Password in server side . thanks for your valuable comments.